# "variable' is not accessed Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
work = False

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def setWork(message):
    work = True
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Мониторинг запущен.\nЧтобы остановить - напишите /stop')
    getInfo()
```

Не могу взаимодействовать с переменной из функции.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def setWork(message):
    work = True
```

Тут `work` - это **локальная** переменная функции `setWork`. Хотите поменять глобальную переменную `work` - укажите питону, что это глобальная переменная.

```
def setWork(message):
    global work
    work = True
```

Но вообще использовать глобальные переменные - не очень хорошая практика. Подумайте, как можно без этого обойтись. Например, используйте какой-то класс для сохранения состояния вашей переменной.